# How to get sum of the count of rows till date from table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

I have a table as below:

TABLE A:

```
id|  on_date |off_date
1 |2020-09-10|
2 |2020-09-09|
3 |2020-09-08|
4 |2020-09-09|2020-09-10
5 |2020-09-08|
```

I want to get the count of ids which are in on mode till a particular date (2020-09-11)

Expected output:

```
count|date
2    |2020-09-08 (because id 3 and 5 has on_date of 2020-09-08)
4    |2020-09-09 (because id 2,3 and 5 has on_date till 09-09-2020)
4    |2020-09-10 (because id 4 not counted because off_date is present and id 1 is added)
```

I am not really sure how to get this output.

Comment: oh you are right my bad. corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

It can be, for example,

```sql
SELECT SUM(dates.a_date >= test.on_date AND (dates.a_date < test.off_date OR test.off_date IS NULL)) `count`, 
       dates.a_date `date`
FROM ( SELECT on_date a_date FROM test 
       UNION 
       SELECT off_date FROM test WHERE off_date IS NOT NULL ) dates
CROSS JOIN test
GROUP BY 2
ORDER BY 2;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=a7ea4a32327ff3de45819b0effc7f862)

`dates` subquery generats dates list when the amount of ON ids might have changed.

`SUM` tests each row against the conditions for particular date and counts the amount of matched rows (testing result is `1` while matching and `0` otherwise).

If some date is absent then look the row with closest lower date.